# Adding binary variable in Gurobi

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi, integer-programming

So I want to add a binary variable `z` where `z[i, j] = 1` when the distance between `i` and `j` are less than or equal to 150 and `z[i, j] = 0` otherwise. I have a list `c` where each `c[i][j]` represents the distance between `i` and `j`. I certainly can't set up `z` as an ordinary binary variable below:

```
y = m.addVars(I, J, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="assign")
```

And I want to add constraints:

```
# One day mailing
m.addConstrs(
    z[i,j] <= y[i,j] for i in I for j in J,
    "Serve")

# Coverage Constraint
m.addConstr(
   quicksum(h[i] * z[i, j] for i in I for j in J) <= 
        0.9 * quicksum(h[i] * y[i, j] for i in I for j in J),
        "Cover")
```

where `h` is a list with integers. How do I set up `z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add `z` as a binary variable:

```
z = m.addVars(I, J, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="z")
```

Then you need constraints to ensure that `z[i, j] = 1` if and only if `c[i, j] <= 150`.
One way to do this is by using indicator constraints:

```
z = 1 -> c <= 150
z = 0 -> c >= 150
```

This is equivalent to

```
c > 150 -> z = 0
c < 150 -> z = 1
```

You add these as follows:

```
m.addConstrs((z[i, j] == 1) >> (c[i][j] <= 150) for i in I for j in J)
m.addConstrs((z[i, j] == 0) >> (c[i][j] >= 150) for i in I for j in J)
```

You can also model this yourself explicitly:
If you have upper and lower bounds `M` and `m` on the value of `c[i][j] - 150` (i.e., `M >= c[i][j] - 150 >= m` for all `i, j`), you can use the following constraints:

```
M * (1-z) >= c - 150
m * z <= c - 150
```

If `c > 150`, the right-hand-sides of both inequalities will be positive. The first one then forces `1 - z = 1` and hence `z = 0`. The second inequality will trivially be satisfied.

If `c < 150`, the right-hand-sides are negative. The first inequality becomes trivial while the second one forces `z = 1`.

For `M` the maximum entry in `c` will do, for `m` you can choose `-150` if all `c[i][j]` are non-negative.

You add these constraints as follows:

```
m.addConstrs( M * (1 - z[i, j]) >= c[i][j] - 150 for i in I for j in J )
m.addConstrs( m * z[i,j] <= c[i][j] - 150 for i in I for j in J )
```

Note that I neglected the case where `c = 150`. This is because for floating point numbers equalities are always only considered to be satisfied within tolerances and hence there is no easy way to distinguish between strict and non-strict inequalities. You can approximate this with an epsilon, e.g.:

```
z = 0 -> c >= 150 + epsilon
```